# end parameter in print in python 3.5 in interactive mode displays result before prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 3.5.1, when running below statement in interactive mode

```
print ("My", "name", "is", end = 'done')
```

the output coming is:

```
My name isdone>>>
```

Why the result is getting displayed before the prompt when end is used?

Comment: Put `\n` manually. `print ("My", "name", "is", end = 'done\n')`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, by default, the `end` parameter of the print function is set to `'\n'`. In your code, you've overwritten that so the pointer is not moved onto the next line. To fix this, simply replace

```
end = 'done'
```

with

```
end = 'done\n'
```

Comment: @Swadeep One other thing that I should perhaps note is that you should prefix the `'done\n'` string with a space since it follows the last word of the message inputted.